# Hibernate inceptor for table/columns creation?

Tags: hibernate

I need modify the DDL when hibernate create a table.

For queries/update can use EmptyInterceptor and override onPrepareStatement, but I don't find anything for table creation/update.

Comment: Hibernate creates a table only at start up. What kind of change do you need to apply?

Comment: I need add aditionals columns that hibernate not use.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an`import.sql` file in the root of your classpath.
Hibernate ORM will run the SQL queries in it after the tables have been created.

For example, assuming you are using PostgreSQL and have an entity mapped to a table `CUSTOMER_TABLE`:

```
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER_TABLE ADD COLUMN secret_column VARCHAR;
```

This way you can update them any way you want.

You can find more details in the [Automatic schema generation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl) paragraph of the Hibernate ORM 6 documentation:

> jakarta.persistence.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files (e.g. import.sql (default value))

> Comma-separated names of the optional files containing SQL DML statements executed during the SessionFactory creation. File order matters, the statements of a given file are executed before the statements of the following one.

> These statements are only executed if the schema is created, meaning that hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto is set to create, create-drop, or update. jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source / jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.drop-script-source should be preferred.

You will also find similar properties [in the Hibernate ORM 5.6 docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl).